# ACE debugging: How to cause msg queue full?

Tags: c++, nonblocking, shutdown, ace, getlasterror

I am using the method:

ACE_Task::putq (ACE_Message_Block *mb, ACE_Time_Value *tv)

Here is the line where I call it: 
ret = putq(mb, const_cast(&ACE_Time_Value::zero));

What I am basically trying is that I need to get regular errors

EWOULDBLOCK and ESHUTDOWN from

int lastErr = ACE_OS::last_error();

in order to debug it right away...

So my question is, it there a simple way how to force such errors ?

I've already tried this: 
       while ( ret >= 0 ) 
          ret = putq(mb, const_cast(&ACE_Time_Value::max_time));

but my thread gets stuck after few calls and never returns from putq...

Many thanx in advance for hints !

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for the first part (EWOULDBLOCK) i can just use:

ACE_Svc_Handler::msg_queue()->high_water_mark(MAX_BUF_SIZE_BYTES);
ACE_Svc_Handler::msg_queue()->low_water_mark(MIN_BUF_SIZE_BYTES);

I assume these fit my needs and what I observe is exactly what I need.

The envoking of ESHUTDOWN error is another problem, and you can simulate it by putting appropriately putting slow down sleep methods.